# Difference between simple wifi transceiver and arduino yun

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-yun, wireless, web

I am debating over getting arduino yun or 2pcs nRF24L01+ 2.4GHz Wireless Transceiver. Here is the link to the transceiver on amazon  [amazon description](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00E594ZX0). I do not know much about wifi but why would someone get the 70 dollar yun instead of the basic transceiver and a uno. In particular for my project I want my arduino to use Web API's like twilio to send messages to my phone. Can both products do that?I know the yun has linux but I don't know if I need that for my project.Is their a better option (price is part of my decision)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nRF24L01+ modules aren't WiFi. They cannot talk to a WiFi router or the internet. They can only talk to other nRF24L01+ modules. They are good for connecting two or more UNOs together.

The Yún has a full WiFi connection and is also able to operate as a router itself. It is best suited when you need to run complex networking on an Arduino.  To access the WiFi on the Yún you need to communicate with it over the in-built serial connection. There are libraries to help you, but the overall package is really very much overkill unless you have a requirement to do complex network routing (VPN for instance) or run software (say a Python program) directly on the Linux portion of the device.

It sounds like what you are really after for your project is an Arduino UNO and [WiFi shield](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoWiFiShield).

Another popular option is the ESP8266 modules.  These can be controlled through serial using *AT* commands, or directly programmed using the Arduino-compatible *core* available from https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino

Comment: Good answer.Would getting a yun be equivalent to getting a UNO and WiFi shield.

Comment: Not entirely. A WiFi shield means the Arduino main chip has control over all aspects of the WiFi connection. On the yun the small Linux computer does the WiFi and you make requests through serial. For that sort of thing the yun is very much overkill.